# Find tangent line of the surface $z = a + 2x^2 + y^2.$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surfaces, parametrization

The question is:
Let $a$ denote a positive constant. Let $L$ denote the line passing through the two points $(6, 5, 4)$ and $(1, 2, 3)$. Let $S$ denote the surface of the elliptic paraboloid $z = a + 2x^2 + y^2.$ If $L$ is tangent to the surface $S$, find the value of $a$.

Does the approach involves finding the tangent plane and check that the plane contains the line??
I am quite confused.

Comment: Sure, one valid approach is to find an equation of the tangent plane at a point $(x_0, y_0, z(x_0, y_0))$ on the surface in terms of $x_0$, $y_0$, and $a$, and then see what those three variables would have to be for that plane to contain the two points known to be on $L$. Or, since the tangent point must be on $L$, another idea would be to first parameterize $L$, then given a point on $L$, find the value of $a$ so that the surface also includes that point, then find the tangent plane to the surface at that point. The second way has the advantage of just one independent variable at a time.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* The surface is convex. Thus it intersects the line in at most two points. If it is tangent to the line, it must intersect it in only one point. Hence if the line is written as $(x,y,z)=(1+5t,2+3t,3+t),$ where $t\in \mathrm R,$ then we want a value of $a$ for which the equation $59t^2+31t+3+a=0$ has only one solution. That is, the discriminant $$31^2-4(59)(3+a)$$ must vanish. Can you complete it now?